# Edit text file by increasing keyword condition (coloumn tree)

Tags: tcl

I am confuse to edit my text file line by line. How to sort line by line with increasing in column tree keyword condition (column tree: 23, 2, 53, n..).

```
set fp [open "data.txt" r]
set filecontent [read $fp]

Text file content:
one, cat, 23,yes,check
two, zebra, 2,yes,check
tree, bird, 53,yes,check
fourth, dog, 15,no,uncheck
five, worm, 9,no,uncheck
six, monkey, 41,yes,uncheck
and so on..

Output text file content:
two, zebra, 2,yes,check
five, worm, 9,no,uncheck
fourth, dog, 15,no,uncheck
one, cat, 23,yes,check
six, monkey, 41,yes,uncheck
tree, bird, 53,yes,check
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is the data that you are really interested in in CSV format? Or is it, like your sample, merely separated by commas? (The real CSV format has some nontrivial quoting rules to allow commas in values.) This matters because there is a standard package for parsing real CSV files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let a list do all work. Use `[lsort -integer -index 2 $lines_list]` where `lines_list` is the list of lines and each line is list too. Tcl will sort list of sublist by third integer sublist element.

```
set fp [open "data.txt" r]
set filecontent [read $fp]
close $fp

set text [split $filecontent \n]
foreach line $text {
    lappend lines_list [split $line ","]
}
set lines_list [lsort -integer -index 2 $lines_list]
set text ""
foreach line $lines_list {
    append text [join $line ","] \n
}

set fout [open "out.txt" w]
puts -nonewline $fout $text
close $fout
```